# file_get_contents() not working for files on local server and accessed via http

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, http, file-get-contents

I'm having problems with a wordpress plugin which works with file_get_contents()
The plugin author said this:

"There is a problem with the way file_get_contents() is configured to work on your server. This is the core PHP function which the Wordpress function wp_remote_get() uses. This function is vital to incorporate any file that is not a part of Wordpress Media library.

The problem with file_get_contents() is that it is not working for files which are there on your local server and accessed via http."

Can anyone tell me what to do or have some spare time to help me? I am not a programmer and have no idea on how to solve this. The hosting company said that the don't offer support for software related issues, pffff!

Best Regards,
Gabriel

Comment: is allow_url_fopen = On set in your php.ini?

Comment: Yes, I look for both fopen and curl, on and installed...

Answer (score 2):

Solved this by using CURL. Here's the code. It will work with remote files e.g. http://yourdomain.com/file.ext

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, ''.$file_path_str.'');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, sprintf("Mozilla/%d.0",rand(4,5)));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$curl_response_res = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
```

Thanks

Comment: any where in your root directory file, like header.php or index.php

Comment: Tried it and it appears as text... I am sorry, not knowing any programming stuff really sucks! :(

Comment: Here's what my hosting company said: "If the script in question is not working for local files via http, I would suggest reviewing the Apache configuration for the server."